# slideToggle double-slides with more than 2 menu tabs

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I wrote this code and it works fine when there's only 2 menus, but as soon as there's 3 or 4, the slideToggle double-slides (blinks).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN"><html><head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {

    $('.menu').hide();

    $('#nav a').click(function(){
        var idvar = this.id;
        var menuid = '#menu_'+idvar;
        $('.menu').not(menuid).slideUp( function(){ 
            $(menuid).slideToggle(); 
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script></head><body>

<div id="nav">
    <a href="#" id="dogs">Dogs</a>
    <a href="#" id="cats">Cats</a>
    <a href="#" id="horses">Horses</a>
    <a href="#" id="cows">Cows</a>
</div>

<div class="menu" id="menu_dogs">stuff about dogs</div>
<div class="menu" id="menu_cats">stuff about cats</div>
<div class="menu" id="menu_horses">stuff about horses</div>
<div class="menu" id="menu_cows">stuff about cows</div>

</body></html>
```

View a demo of the issue: (delete any two menus to see it working how it's intended) 
http://jsfiddle.net/ANDXJ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mrtsherman said, you are trying to slideup ALL menu items, you need to slide up only the visible one. To preserve your slide up slide down transitions i had to add a little more logic in. Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ANDXJ/3/).

Comment: Thank you! This answer successfully keeps the buttons' functionality of toggling the slide, so if Cat is already open and I click the Cat button, Cat closes.

Comment: Yeah, i thought you might want that :-) The code could use some tweaking but it covers all scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

This line is the problem:

```
 $('.menu').not(menuid).slideUp( function(){ 
     $(menuid).slideToggle(); 
 });
```

What you are saying is - for every menu item that is not the current one, slideUp the text and then slide down the current menu item. This is executing multiple times. Hence the reason why you get multiple flashes. You want to do this one time. So separate it into different statements. Slide up all menus. Then slide down current one.

Here - this should do what you want.

```
$('#nav a').click(function() {
    var idvar = this.id;
    var menuid = '#menu_' + idvar;

    $('.menu').hide();        
    $(menuid).slideDown();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the problem with the multiple executions.